# 'Start Use <App Name>' VS 'Start Using <App Name>'

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, american-english, contractions

We are working on a paywall page within our app. The app is called Retouch. We were wondering what is the right way to showcase the title of the paywall.

- Start Use Retouch
- Start Using Retouch

Is there a difference? I'm not an English speaker. Thanks!

Comment: The 2nd version with “using” is idiomatic and sounds better.

Comment: Start Retouch may be all you need. But how do you use paywall within app Retouch, and you want to start the app you're already in? Start Paywall?

Comment: You need to hire an editor. We don't do this here.

Comment: Thinking about further, I don’t think “start using retouch” is ideal either. The app is, I assume, already running, and after the paywall page the user can access to extra paid-for functions. Something like ‘Get Full Access’ or ‘Premium Access’ seems better. Take a look a few websites with paywalls- what terms do they use?

Comment: As you consider why the question closed, notice that "Take a look ... what terms do they use?" can sound like asking strangers to do the heavy lifting ... for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Start Use Retouch** is not grammatical. You need a gerund after a verb like "start".

**Start Using Retouch** is grammatical and is a much better choice.

If you need a short phrase then **Start Retouch** is also correct and grammatical, and is shorter. It would be normal usage on a label.